# ECS will not launch instance, "unable to place a task because the resources could not be found."

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I cannot figure out why my ecs service will not launch, and keep being given the error "service unable to place a task because the resources could not be found".

In my task definition, I have 500 cpu units dedicated and 250 memory, for just a very small sample node app that's just serving up my static assets.

I am launching my service with 1 task and no ELB.

Comment: Have you checked that another task that you previously created didn't occupy port 80?

Comment: I have no other tasks

Comment: Hey, have you set the task definitions resource hard/soft limits?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that your cpu units is too high.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment

it's a harder metric to guess if you haven't really measured it much on your app.

anyway, i'm hitting a similar issue, so i'm right there in the same boat, but i'd try erasing the cpu since it is optional and see if that resolves it.